# Weak Derivative is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If the weak derivative of some function $u$ on a open connected set is 0. Does it mean that $u$ is constant almost everywhere on the given set?

Comment: Sounds good to me!  Should be easy to prove by definition of weak derivative.